# HTML5 Canvas font size

Tags: html, text, canvas

When I translate and scale the canvas, the text put on the canvas corresponds to the canvas scale.  How can I make it fixed size regardless of the scale of the canvas?

Say I have a canvas that I used scale so even though the size is 640x480 pixels, the scaling is such that it is 8x5 canvas units.  If I now use `context.fillText`, the text will be HUGE.  I need the text to always be same visual size, say 12px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to temporarily reset the scale (aka set the transformation matrix back to identity) before drawing your text.

```
// I have lots of transforms right now
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
// Will always draw text in normal scale
ctx.fillText("lalalala", x, y);
ctx.restore();
// Still have my old transforms
```

Comment: That IS actually the only way.  As in addition to scaling, rotation will be taken into account when drawing text.  So a vertically flipped canvas will have upside down font.